# Adding two columns in Excel together using two different lists

Tags: database, arrays, excel

This is my first time using this site but my problem is; 
I have a list of numbers in column A, which have values in column B. Then I have a longer list in column C with values in column D. Column C has many of the numbers in column A.

What I'm trying to do is add Column B and Column D together based on the numbers that match up in column A and column C.

For example:

COLUMN A
1234/
1567/
2234

COLUMN B (these are the values for column A)
1,245/
5,432
2,767

COLUMN C (these values have similar, not the same, numbers as column A)
2234
1787
2902

COLUMN D(these are the values for column C)
2,345
5,675
1,459

What I want to do: Site number #2234 (Cell A3 and C1) = 2,767(B3) + 2,345 (D1) = 5112

Comment: Is this a one time thing? should it be automatic? Can you use a button with a vba routine? What do you want to do with the value (5112) - do you also want to keep the other values? where? in what order?

Answer (score 0):

ried manually, used Vlookup and sum functions, this is easy and simple method.

1. copy the **Column A** and **Column C** list into new single **column F** and remove duplicates.
2. add, **=vlookup(f2, A:B, 2,0)** formula in **'G2'** cell, assuming 1st row is header.
3. add, **=vlookup(f2, C:D, 2,0)** formula in **'H2'** cell, assuming 1st row is header.
4. add, **=sum(F2:G2)** in cell **'I2'** assuming 1st row is header.
5. Drag or copy the formulas cell till the list ends.

Step 1 may be neglected, since it works if only List(item) is present in both **Column A** and **column C**. but it is necessary to copy One list Either **Column A** or **column C**
to **Column F**.

Atlast apply filter to column **I** and unselect **#N/A**.